# Problems with preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, arduino

I wanted to write a debug log print function for my finite state machine that prints the current state, the time in milliseconds and then my message. However, I get random results. This is what I did:

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT(tag, format, ...) printf("[%10s] %7d: " format "\n", tag, millis(), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

When I run:

```
DEBUG_PRINT("SETUP", "%d %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I expect to get: `[     SETUP]       0: 1 2 3 4`
         But I get: `[     SETUP]       0: 0 1 2 3`

Adding an extra %d will get the "4", but I still get an spurious 0.

My previous debut log macro: `DEBUG_PRINT1("%d %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3, 4);` prints the expected `1 2 3 4`.

Can you help me to get rid of that extra 0?

Comment: Are you sure you are using c++? This looks like C to me

Comment: Needs more [mcve]. Also, what do you see when you look at the generated preprocessor output?

Comment: It [seems to work for me...](https://ideone.com/QNlg2L) - are you sure this is the actual code ? Please put together a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Paul R have to test in Sketch, I guess, it's not a standard compiler

Comment: @melpomene actuallyit does, some nonstandard compilers do. more of,  microsoft and gcc treat variadic templates differently. though in this case problem was long arrgumenr

Comment: Why using MACRO instead of regular function ?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I'll try do post better questions in the future. @IanA.B.King , I tagged it C++ because the Arduino environment uses C++. I thought on tagging it C, but then somebody would have asked me why did I tag it C :D
Jarod42 I guess you can asl that about 99% of macro users. I guess I see it as a piece of code simple enough not to deserve its own function. I don't see any benefit to it, and on the error I had, it wouldn't have helped me to troubleshoot it.

Comment: *"I guess you can ask that about 99% of macro users."* And it is what I try to do. When regulars function do the job, use function. use MACRO only when needed. (You can even use printf format attribute for your function to also have warning when type mismatch with format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `millis()` function returns an `unsigned long`, where as the identifier is a `%d` integer.

Change it to `%7ld` and it should work fine.

I have tested it.

edit 1:

I have also tested it on a linux system. In the linux system this is not a problem there because the size of a linux `int` is 4 bytes and `long` is 8 bytes.

On the Arduino however, the size of an `int` is 2 bytes and `long` is 4 bytes. This screws up the `%d` identifier on the Arduino, and extends the `unsigned long` from `millis()` to the next `%d`

Comment: It might be worth adding a note that having compiler warnings enabled would have flagged this problem immediately, thereby saving a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @PaulR until recently arduino did not had printf (and compiler support for it), no native warnings . Note, we dont have any output but  rs232oUSB and pins, so this can be replacement , source code available on playground.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And Paul, you are totally right, I will keep them enabled.

Comment: @Swift: that seems unfortunate, to say the least, especially given that the Arduino market is presumably mainly hobbyists and novice programmers. Is the compiler not based on gcc (which has had printf warnings for at least 15 years) ?

Comment: @PaulR it is based on gnu toolchain and LLVM as far as i can tell, but provided that even stub program doesn't match ISO - you have two entry points to program `loop()` and `setup()` and set of compiler flags available seems smaller. Last time i did dwell there was before Due and other new fancy boards, it could be changed

Comment: I think it's precisely the fact that is being oriented to novice programmers what hides the warnings by default. You can activate them in the preferences, and yes, that would have probably saved me asking this question.